# Overriding method with generic return type

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a super-class that defines the following abstract method

```
public abstract <T extends Interface> Class<T> getMainClass();
```

Now if I want to override it in some sub-class

```
public Class<Implementation> getMainClass(){
    return Implementation.class;
}
```

I get a warning about type safety and unchecked conversion:

> Type safety: The return type `Class<Implementation>` for `getMainClass()` from the type `SubFoo` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Class<Interface>` from the type `SuperFoo`

Doesn't `Class<Implementation>` fall under `Class<T>` if `<T extends Interface>`? Is there any way to properly get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the overriding method's return type must be a subtype of the overridden method's return type.

`Class<Impl>` is not a subtype of `Class<T>` where `<T extends Interface>`. T is unknown here.

`Class<Impl>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends Interface>`, per subtyping rules.

---

some subtyping rules regarding wildcards:

for any type X

- `A<X>` is a subtype of `A<? extends X>`
- `A<X>` is a subtype of `A<? super X>`

if `S` is subtype of `T`

- `A<? extends S>` is a subtype of `A<? extends T>`
- `A<? super T>` is a subtype of `A<? super S>`

More concisely, ( `<:` means "is a subtype of" )

```
A<S>    <:    A<? extends S>    <:    A<? extends T>

A<T>    <:    A<?  super  T>    <:    A<?  super  S>
```

Comment: This solved the problem completely. Thank you. On a sidenote, what would be a good reference for these kinds of questions on generics, explaining e.g. subtyping rules?

Comment: There's [Angelika Langer's generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) - it covers just about every edge case, and yet each section is (relatively) easy to take in and understand.

Comment: @alh84001 unfortunately, I don't know a better source than Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following scenario similar to yours:

```
public class SuperFoo {
     public abstract <T extends Interface> List<T> getList();
} 

public class SubFoo extends SuperFoo {
     private List<Implementation> l = new ArrayList<Implementation>();

     public List<Implementation> getList() {
          return l;
     }

     public void iterate() {
          for (Implementation i: l) ...;
     }
}

SubFoo subFoo = new SubFoo();
SuperFoo superFoo = subFoo;
superFoo.getList().add(new AnotherImplementation()); // Valid operation!
subFoo.iterate(); // Unexpected ClassCastException!
```

In this case unchecked conversion warning warns you about possibility of unexpected `ClassCastException`.

However, in your case, when return type is `Class<...>`, it's not a problem (as far as I understand), so you can legally suppress a warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Class<Implementation> getMainClass(){ ... }
```

Another option is to make `SuperFoo` itself generic:

```
public class SuperFoo<T extends Interface> {
    public abstract Class<T> getMainClass(); 
}

public class SubFoo extends SuperFoo<Implementation> {
    public Class<Implementation> getMainClass() { ... }
}
```

For yet another (and perhaps the best) option see Stas Kurilin's answer.

Comment: Thank you on the clarification. I guess I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Hm.. I think your solution better)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public abstract Class<? extends Interface> getMainClass();
```

**reorganized example** 
by such warnings java tried prevents cases like this

```
class OtherImpl implements Interface{ 
} 
A a = new B();//where A - your abstract class and B - implementation
Class<OtherImpl> other = a.<OtherImpl>getMainClass();//some broken think, But _without_ runtime exception
```

*As @axtavt mentioned example was broken. I reorganized it.*

Comment: It wouldn't cause exception due to type erasure.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It makes things clearer. Unfortunately I get the same warning when using your suggestion, but that is what I expected. I guess I'll leave it like it was.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have something like `public abstract Class<? extends Interface> getMainClass();` rather than `public abstract Interface getMainClass();`?

I think you can simply return an instance of `Interface`, and then, if the caller wants to have access to the underlying runtime class can simply call `getClass()` on the returned object.

Essentially, I think you can simply do

```
public InterfaceImpl implements Interface {
    // ...
};

public abstract class A {
    public abstract Interface getMainClass();
    // ...
}

public class AImpl {
    return new InterfaceImpl();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AImpl aImpl = new AImpl();
        Interface i = aImpl.getMainClass();
        System.out.println(i.getClass());
    }
}
```