# Convert List of Promises into Promise of List in Play Framework

Tags: java, generics, playframework, type-mismatch

I want to convert a `List<Promise<Boolean>>` into a `Promise<List<Boolean>>`. I know that this can be achieved using the [`sequence`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#sequence%28java.lang.Iterable%29) method, but I'm having some problems getting the types right.

Here is what I've tried:

#### First (naive) approach

```
List<Promise<Boolean>> foo = new ArrayList<Promise<Boolean>>;

// ... Code that loops over some other collection
// and adds multiple Promise<Boolean>s to foo

Promise<List<Boolean>> bar = Promise.sequence(foo);
```

This does not compile because "the argument type `List<Promise<Boolean>>` does not conform to formal parameter type `Iterable<Promise<? extends A>>`".

#### Second approach

Declaring the type of `foo` to conform to the formal parameter type as suggested by the error message above:

```
List<Promise<? extends Boolean>> foo = new ArrayList<Promise<Boolean>>()
```

As per the sub-typing rules laid out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163253/1199226), `Promise<Boolean>` should be a subtype of `Promise<? extends Boolean>`, but I am getting a type mismatch here: "cannot convert from `ArrayList<F.Promise<Boolean>>` to `List<F.Promise<? extends Boolean>>`.

#### Third approach

Removing type information from instantiation of `ArrayList<Promise<Boolean>>`:

```
List<Promise<? extends Boolean>> foo = new ArrayList();
```

This compiles but results in a warning about unchecked conversion that I would like to get rid of: "The expression of type `ArrayList` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `List<F.Promise<? extends Boolean>>`."

---

What am I missing? How can I get the types to line up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this declaration instead:

```
List<Promise<? extends Boolean>> foo = new ArrayList<Promise<? extends Boolean>>();
```

Check the following answers to understand why this works:

- [Generic method vs wildcard - compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19643414/1679863)
- [What are multi-level wild cards? Confusion in syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18194956/1679863)
- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745/1679863)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works, but only in that it removes any warnings/compilation issues for the line where I am declaring `foo`. Unfortunately, though, it prevents me from adding any `Promise<Boolean>`s to `foo` before calling `sequence` on it: "The method `add` in type `List` is not applicable for the arguments `F.Promise<Boolean>`.

Comment: Ok, then what you can do is, fill up your list first, and then after that assign it to the `foo` reference with the above type, and then pass it to `sequence()` method. That's because you cannot add anything to `List<? extends SomeType>` kind of lists.

Comment: And what should that temporary list be declared as? Because when I do `List<Promise<Boolean>> temp = new ArrayList<Promise<Boolean>>();`, I can `add` to `temp` just fine but after assigning `temp` to `foo` via `foo = temp;`, passing `foo` to `sequence()` won't work. The error message is basically the same as the one I got for my first approach.

Comment: @itsjeyd Is your foo of type `List<? extends Promise<? extends Boolean>> foo`?

Comment: @itsjeyd Ah! A minor mistake. I've updated the answer. Actually, you don't need to create a `temp` list. Just the above one would work.

Comment: ... because `ArrayList<Promise<? extends Boolean>>` trivially extends `List<Promise<? extends Boolean>>`. Of course. :) Case closed, thanks.