# Overriding method with generic return type with no warning

Tags: java, generics

Simple question: I have a bounded generic method I want to `@Override`.

```
class Stuff {}
class SeriousStuff extends Stuff {}

interface Overridable {
    <T extends Stuff> T getStuff();
}
```

How can I do this without parametrizing the whole `Overridable` interface and without unchecked-conversion warnings?

```
class SeriourExample implements Overridable {
    SeriousStaff getStuff() { return new SeriousStuff(); }
    ||
    \/
    /* WARNING: Type safety: The return type SeriousStaff for
     * getStuff() from the type SeriourExample needs unchecked 
     * conversion to conform to T from the type Overridable
     */
}
```

If adding a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is still *polite* and fair, then ok for me.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144896/overriding-method-with-generic-return-type), but still I am not able to exploit the proposed solution because I cannot use a `?` wildcard.

Thanks to `? extends Reader` for you help (that's a terrible one I know.. couldn't resist.)

Comment: I think, you cannot.

Comment: Here, `T` is not a generic from the class but for the method itself. Hence, it does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @Arnaud: imho it can make sense when `Overridable` is involved in a complex hierarchy tree, and you don't want to pollute your code with generic annotations when creating/defining/returning those objects. ?

Comment: @Campa I rephrase : if `T` was on the class like `Overridable<T extends Stuff>`, then it would make sense to create a `SeriourExample implements Overridable<SeriousStuff>` but here, as `T` is on the method, it can potentially return different subclasses of `Stuff` with the same instance. That is why I think that it is not possible to restrict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just get rid of the generics and use a covariant return type:

```
interface Overridable {
  Stuff getStuff();
}

class SeriourExample implements Overridable {
  @Override SeriousStuff getStuff() { ... }
}
```

Comment: I guess so... God I've been in a generics-hell for hours to the point I see generics all over the place and forgot about the covariant return type.

Comment: But.. what if I need generics instead? In a slightly more complex scenario, there might be 2 subclasses of `SeriousStuff` (`VerySeriousStuff` and `TooSeriousStuff`), so that `SeriousExample` would not know which one it will get, and at the same time I don't want to erase up to `SeriousStuff` upper class. ?

Comment: Then use generics at the interface/class level, not the method level.

Comment: Yup.  T needs to be a type parameter of the class, not the method.